# Algorithm for tracking changes in value over time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, algorithm

I am writing a rails app that deals with product inventory. I would like to include the following features, and am struggling with developing an efficient algorithm:

- View stock history (how many were in stock on each date)
- Quantity removed from warehouse, and quantity added to warehouse over specific periods of time
- Amount of time the product was out of stock in any given period

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the best way of tracking changes? In addition to my Products
   table, should I create another table called
   HistoricProductQuantities, and insert a new record each time there
   is a change in the quantity?
2. What number should I track? The historic stock quantity (i.e. 50 in
       stock on this day, 24 in stock on that day), or the CHANGE in stock
       quantity i.e. -5 (5 sold) or 15 (15 added to inventory)? Or do I
       track both in separate tables?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend implementing Date Dimensions on your application, as it seems like you will be doing a lot of Time related calculations. Search on Google for date dimensions as it's beyond the scope of your questions. That said, I believe it will be of great benefit for your app to implement and use date dimensions.

As far as your direct questions go:

`What is the best way of tracking changes? In addition to my Products table, should I create another table called HistoricProductQuantities, and insert a new record each time there is a change in the quantity?`

Yes you could do this, I would probably call it HistoricProductSnapshot and keep track of the product activity in there on daily basis. With this information as well as time dimensions you could do calculations such as "how many of Product X Did we have 5 days ago or a month ago etc etc."

`What number should I track? The historic stock quantity (i.e. 50 in stock on this day, 24 in stock on that day), or the CHANGE in stock quantity i.e. -5 (5 sold) or 15 (15 added to inventory)? Or do I track both in separate tables?`

I do not have experience writing inventory control software but I believe with the Snapshot table I mentioned on the question above you would only have to keep track of quantities per day. The Change in product counts could then be calculated from your snapshot table. You could for example have a function that will output the product amount in a given time range as an array. Example: From March 1 to March 7 these were the stock amounts for Product Y `[45,40,39,27,22,45,44]`.

Hope that helps. As I said I am not a product inventory guy but I have worked with Point of Sales Systems and the procedure above should give you a could enough start for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there any inefficiency with recording the quantity each day even if it doesn't change? For example if I have 3000 products and I am tracking the quantity each day, that is over 1 million database records per year...isn't that a lot?

Comment: Sure, it's a lot of data... but do you want to keep it or not? That's the question. Daily snapshots would be the most standardized way of collecting your inventory. You could theoretically not save the data if it does not change and take that into consideration when performing your calculations, however I don't think it's the right way to go. That's like Google saying "we are not saving today's web page visitors for your website because you did not receive any". Again, I have no training in inventory management or analytics but if you want historical data that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. From a database perspective, is having a few million records for a small app normal? Should i worry about performance issues (running on heroku)? I have very little experience with large databases... (but maybe this is not even large for all i know). Thanks for all your advice thus far, its been very helpful.

Comment: No problem. A free heroku database will only allow you to have 10,000 rows, so yes. If you upgrade to the next tier I believe 10,000,000 rows is the limit.

Comment: i already upgraded but i meant more about performance issues? and querying tables with so many records all the time..?

Answer (score 1):

This gem could be usefull for tracking changes in models https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Answer (score 1):

Keep the data raw. I would personally create a new data entry every day, displaying how much items you have in stock per day. Or you can make the interval much shorter, such as every 12 hours.

For our particular use case:

We had a table called Days, which had a many to many relationship with products, and each "relationship" will have a value called quantity (to keep track of quantity of product per day). Additionally per relationship, we had another value for the relationship with transactions (a one to many relationship) that has the entries for the time of transaction and remaining stocks.

I would personally advise you to use the quantity of stock as the raw data, as it will enable you to gather the data such as how much items were removed during a certain transaction, when the item was out of stock and when it became in stock, all through the data. When you have data in which you need to perform statistical calculations on, it's best to store this data as raw values (quantity of the item).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I store the raw quantity for each day, is there an easy way to calculate quantity sold over a period of time? And quantity restocked? For example if there is an array [10,8,6,15,14], that would be a total of 5 sold and 9 restocked, but is there an easy rails way to calculate that?

Comment: Not exactly sure if there is a "easy" rails way (I've been using asp.net MVC), but the concept should be the same. Any "increase" in value from one to the next is "restocked" and any "decrease" would be sold. By reading the table of values that retuns `{10, 8, 6, 15, 14}`, I would have two variables `sold` and `restocked`. Subtract two values at a time. 10 - 8 = 2, which means 2 sold during this transaction. 8 - 6 = 2, 4 sold in total. 6 - 15 = -9, 9 restocked and 4 sold. 15 - 14 = 1, 5 sold and 9 restocked. Should be a very simple O(n) solution.

Comment: Statistics works best IMO when you store the data as quantity. This way whenever you encounter any other problem, there will always be ways to easily work with your data to get the values that you need.